# LT codes with constant degree on information symbols

Tags: coding-theory

I have just read a [Luby’s paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby_transform_code) on the very basic idea of the LT codes, which may be of interest for me.
For my application, encoding k information symbols is done in a process that generates a big table T of size k’.
Then, for every information symbol s, choose d indices in the table $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ and add s to $T[x_i]$ (And beside $T[x_i]$ store the index of s, but I ignore this for the question).

So basically this is exactly as the encoding of the LT codes except that the degree distribution of the code words is not the same. So I wonder if there is an analysis of this variant.
Do you know a paper that treats this variant? Any thoughts on why it should/shouldn’t work?

Comment: Have you tried adapting Luby’s analysis?

Comment: His analysis is based on the "Soliton" distribution over the degree of the code-symbols. Since it is not my main field I wanted first to check if there is already such an adaptation as it seem general enough to me.

Comment: Your question is not transfered, just duplicated. Maybe delete original post?